# Как последовательно посчитать сумму n элементов в массиве?

Tags: python, list

Пример: есть список `change(3,5,7,1,6,8,2,4)`  и в нем мне надо сложить последовательные группы - "окна" - по 3 элемента от каждого элемента в списке:

```
3+5+7 ==> 5+7+1 ==> 7,1,6 ==> 1,6,8
```

и т.д.`

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: брать по три элемента и складывать. "Последующие три" это не 5,7,1, а 1, 6, 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы хотите реализовать сумму элементов в скользящем окне из трех элементов:

```
data = [3,5,7,1,6,8,2,4]
res = [sum(data[i:i+3]) for i in range(len(data))]
print(res);

Вывод:
[15, 13, 14, 15, 16, 14, 6, 4]
```

Чтобы понять, как работают срезы для последних элементов результата:

```
print( [data[i:i+3] for i in range(len(data))] )

Вывод:
[[3, 5, 7], [5, 7, 1], [7, 1, 6], [1, 6, 8], [6, 8, 2], [8, 2, 4], [2, 4], [4]]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Что будем использовать:

Есть такая функция как [sum()](https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/vstroennye-funktsii-interpretatora-python/funktsija-sum/). Она находит сумму чисел массива (она может находить и другое, но здесь это не нужно).

Будем брать так называемый [срез](https://pythonru.com/biblioteki/indeksy-srezy-i-iteracija) массива. То есть из массива берем, допусти, только 1-й, 2-й, 3-й элементы.

[len()](https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/vstroennye-funktsii-interpretatora-python/funktsija-len/) - длина массива. 
[range()](https://python-scripts.com/range) - диапазон.

---

## Реализация

Воспользуемся следующей командой:

```
summ = [sum(ar[i : i+3]) for i in range(len(ar))]
```

Объясняю:

- `for i in range(len(ar))` - цикл в количество итераций, равное длине массива ar
- `ar[i : i+3]` - срез массива с элемента i до элемента i+3, то есть 3 элемента: ar[i], ar[i+1], ar[i+2]
- `sum(ar[i : i+3])` - сумма трех элементов среза
- Все это обернуто в [], то есть мы в цикле проходимся, находим сумм**ы** таких блоков по 3. Получаем в итоге массив сумм sum.

## Пример

```
ar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
summ = [sum(ar[i : i+3]) for i in range(len(ar))]
print(summ);
```

Вывод:

```
[6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 17, 9]
```

**P.S.** Если мы будем брать предпоследний элемент, то будет происходить нахождение лишь **2** последних элементов. Последним будет нахождение суммы 1 последнего элемента, то есть сам последний элемент. Если вам нужно остановится на предпредпоследнем элементе, вы можете регулировать `range(len(ar))` и изменять на `range(len(ar)-2)` и так далее.